Is is possible to ignore / preserve changes to certain settings?
We use the Jenkins Job DSL plugin to store our Jenkins job definitions as code within our repo. We have a job set up to periodically regenerate the jobs based on the version-controlled DSL seed files, so the jobs automatically update when changes are made to the Job DSL seed files in the VCS repo, which works pretty well.
However, there are a handful of job settings that we don't want to be forced to stay in sync with the version-controlled seed file. One simple example is the job schedule (ie, the schedule for the "Build Periodically" build trigger). We don't want to have to submit / review / land changes into the actual VCS repo just to change how frequently the automated test job runs, since we change schedules semi-frequently based on external / meta factors such as approaching release dates, number of active branches, trying to troubleshoot a flaky test, etc.
So, is there any way to prevent Job DSL from resetting certain, specific job settings to their "factory" state every time it runs? I've experimented a bit with trying to store settings in config files (via the "Config File Provider" plugin), but Job DSL also reverts config files attached to the folder to their factory state when it runs, and defining job schedules in a separate config file is kind of awkward anyway.

Disclaimer

That's not very common and I would say that's an antipattern method.
JobDSL and IaC architectures should ensure full reproducibility.

Yet

Yet, If you are forced to, this process can solve your issue.

In your deploy VCS, you would have a "job" list defined in a static
YAML file in your CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG folder.


    jobs:
    - jobs1
    - jobs2


I would assume your deployment CI should detect which job was modified then create dynamically the jobs.yml file.
This way after deployment, it would only set the jobs defined and forget about the others.
Normally, your non-updated jobs will still appear because they still exist in your persistent jenkins data volume.

